# How to make a user profile as an Active user profile?

Tags: user-profile, 2007, shared-service-provider, administration

User account exists & active in AD however the user profile is showing under "Profile Missed from Import" in SSP, how to make this user profile as an Active Profile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user profile is shown under missing profiles, it has been previously imported. Have you made any changes to the profile import filter or moved the user in AD to a location that is not covered by the import?

Answer (score 1):

Try reimporting your users from your Active Directory, making sure the connections are all correct(ed)